# UNIX word count refined by tcl_startOfNextWord and tcl_startOfPreviousWord

Tags: shell, unix, pipeline

I am trying to achieve a C-shell script that counts lines and characters. So far, I know that there is a command wc that counts words. I want to refine the result of wc with tcl_startOfNextWord and tcl_startOfPreviousWord because I want to redefine the separator of words. I want to make any word separated by a hyphen, such as one-two, be read as two words instead of one. Same thing with colons (one:two). I did a `man` command of both `tcl_startOfNextWord` and `tcl_startOfPreviousWord` but I could not figure out what I need to do in order to establish both : and - as end/beginning of a new word.

Could someone point me into the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need the correct result, or are you learnng about `tcl_startOf*`? You could just include a `sed 's/[-:]/ /g'` in your processing stream to convert "twinned" words into separate words. Good luck.

Comment: I just figured `tcl_startOf` was the correct approach. I do need the correct result. I am learning UNIX on my own but I really want to get the correct word count. How can I include sed after my wc -w -l command in my shell script? THANKS A LOT!

Comment: If you are learning UNIX then I don't recommend csh, which is not used much these days.  You will find that Korn shell (ksh) and bash (particularly on Linux) are far more common.